# How can I append text from a UITextField to an array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have done this before and I managed to forget how I did it. I want to be able to have a user type in a textfield and have that information added into a empty array.

```
var textFieldArray = [String]()
```

Comment: `textFieldArray.append(someTextField.text!)`

Comment: Thank you! If you switch this to an answer happy to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UITextField` can never return `nil` for its `text` property, so it is safe to force unwrap it.  You can simply call `.append` on the array to append the text:

```
textfieldArray.append(someTextField.text!)
```